# Problems Inserting Wireless Card into Mini PCI express port.

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard, computer-building, pci-express

I'm new to computer building. I have everything working except my wireless card. In the question section of [this Intel wireless card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N7474CS), it says it works with any computer with a mini PCIe slot, which my [GIGABYTE GA-B250M-DS3H motherboard](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128980) has two of. However, I can't figure out how to insert the wireless card into the mini PCIe slot--it seems to be too wide (see picture). Am I missing something obvious here? Are these parts not actually compatible?

[image]

Comment: If I follow your link I see a full size PCIe x16 slot, a full sized PCI-e x1 slot, a full sized PCI-e x1 slot, and no ** mini PCI-e slots. While the card is not PCI-e but MINI PCI-e. [the manual](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-B250M-DS3H-rev-10#sp) confirms this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Mini-PCIe card (for a laptop).

You're trying to put it in a full size PCIe slot (which looks like a desktop motherboard).

Laptops have mini-PCI slots.  Desktops have the full size PCIe slot.

That said, you can still do it, you just need one of these.  Search for "Mini-PCIE to PCIE adapter".  As you can see they make kinds that have wiring for external antennas.

I've noticed some desktop motherboards have one actual Mini-PCI slots for Bluetooth/wireless cards - but yours may not.  So you would need one these adapters.

[image]

PCIe has a concept called "lanes" - x1, x4, x8, x16 refer to the number of "lanes" the connector has.  More lanes = faster.

Graphics cards typically are x16 (the full length) and the longest slot is intended for those types of cards.  Less bandwidth-intensive cards like RAID or Wi-Fi require less PCIe bandwidth and so can use the smaller slots.

The CPU has a limited number of lanes it can support (32, 48) so all slots usually aren't x16 (unless you don't want other peripherals than graphics cards).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Why then is the much longer (3-4) times longer PCI port on the motherboard also labeled as "PCI express" when it is much different than the small one? Also, I'm so confused by the fact that the "mini PCIe" is wider than the PCIe...

Comment: See edits.  Mini-PCIe likely refers to the thickness rather than the width.

Comment: @LawerenceC Thanks for the edits explaining all the different ports in detail, very useful stuff.